# Should I lock tables on every insert/update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it the norm to lock tables on every insert and/or update?

If so why? To avoid duplicate exact time additions? Any other reasons?

Comment: It is not the norm to _manually_ lock tables when inserting/updating. The DBMS' engine should handle that for you in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should definitely not lock the table for every insert or update.

The database itself automatically locks the part of the table that is needed to keep data integrity. Locking the entire table for a single insert or update only makes a lock that is larger than neccessary.

Locking a table can be used as an alternative to transactions, and would be used when you need to do more than one operation on the table that are depending on each other.